# My styled seekBar in android studio is not working as it should

Tags: android

I have a seek bar with the following xml file

```
 <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/styled_progress"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumbler_small"
        android:indeterminate="false" />
```

and in styled_progress I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress_cyan"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress_red"/>

</layer-list>
```

but I can see only the red part everywhere, the cyan part is not appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your styled_progress.xml as, Because you are using wrong ids, you have to use 
**For Background**

```
  android:id="@android:id/background"
```

**For Progress**

```
android:id="@android:id/progress"
```

**For secondaryProgress**

```
 android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
```

and check yours.

---

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background" 
android:drawable="@drawable/progress_red"/>

    <item
     android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress_cyan"/>
    <item
       android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress_red"/>

    </layer-list>
```

Comment: you added an extra > at each id. I tried that too but my secondaryProgress is not shown, the line after the thumbThing is white not red

Comment: Try to add   android:id="@android:id/background" as i update my answer

Comment: Thanks. That worked... I understand now why it hasn't worked before